# how to get the information of the person who has logged in , in a new activity in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

i have written a program to register a user with the help of name , contact , aadharno and security hint , so when i register a user the data gets saved inside my sqlite database and i have kept only aadharno as a username to login to my application , so whenever i enter the aadharno , i m successfully inside my application. 
Now , i have a new activity and i have a textview named aadharno , so whenever i click on login it takes me to this activity but my aadharno is not getting set inside my textview , please need some help.

My code for the above : the below code works fine when i register my aadharno and with the same aadharno i am able to login inside my application.

```
public String getSingleEntry(String aadhar) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(Db_Governance.TABLE_NAME, null,
            Db_Governance.AADHAR_NO + " =?", new String[] { aadhar }, null,
            null, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() < 1) // UserName Not Exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password = cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(Db_Governance.AADHAR_NO));
    cursor.close();
    return password;
}
```

In My new acivity :

```
txtAadhaar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textAadhar1);
dbGovernance = new Database_Governance(getBaseContext());
dbGovernance.open(getBaseContext());

String user = txtAadhaar.getText().toString();
String password = dbGovernance.getSingleEntry(user);
if (user.equals(password)) {
    txtAadhaar.setText(password);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Aadhar No does not match",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Whenever i enter my new activity , it shows the else part message.Please suggest what changes do i have to make.
Thanking you in advance

Comment: I don't understand. Why should user and password be the same?

Comment: because password(aadharno) is coming from database and user is what i want to set

Comment: and sir even if i remove it , i get "NOT EXIST" in my textview

Comment: Which means, whatever you search in the DB does not exist. Try to insert some log statements so that you know which values your variables have. Alternatively you could also run the app with the debugger.

Comment: there will be some userID of user, use it.

Comment: @Henry sir when i debugged it , it shows me "NOT EXIST" on password

Comment: @TusharPandey ok sir i will try using it

Comment: i think you have to follow proper way to expose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user String will be empty as you have not set any value on the txtAdhaar TextView hence it will return empty string.
 you need to set the value of txtAdhaar before getting it's value in user String. 
To Set value on txtAdhaar you can user Bundle to send the  aadhar no. that user has entered while login to your other Activity and set its value on txtAdhaar before using.

write the following code in onclick of your login button when you move to new activity by creating a new intent as shown:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,className.class);
i.putExtra("aadhar_no", aadharNo);
startActivity(i);
```

here aadharNo is the no. entered by user while login
then in your other activity onCreate you can get the data as shown:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
txtAadhar.setText(i.getStringExtra("aadhar_no"));
```

write this code before you fetch the value of txtAadhar ie before this line
    String user = txtAadhar.getText.toString();